# How to stop redirecting to /app

Tags: cloudflare

My site is on cloud flare for almost an year.  All of sudden for last one week site is down with redirect loop error.  Cloudflare is automatically adding /app at the end of the URL and doing a infinite redirect.  This is what I see

curl -v http://manuals-store.com

response has
Location: https://manuals-store.com/app

This is constantly redirecting itself.  Can anyone please help me how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Set two aliases in OpenShift:

- `example.com`, and
- `www.example.com`.

I had the same redirecting issue to `/app` when I used `CNAME` (in the Cloudflare) to connect to my OpenShift application.

NOTE: If you get an error in the OpenShift UI for any reason, use the `rhc` command
`rhc alias add <application name> <custom domain name>`

I know it is a late answer, but I hope it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Cloudflare is automatically adding /app"

We actually wouldn't add anything to your existing urls. I did a curl against the domain and IP address (the one that is found on the CNAME) and the redirect is directly on your server.

Comment: The CNAME is pointing to manuals-labapp.rhcloud.com.  If do


`curl -v http://manuals-labapp.rhcloud.com`

I get the actual page.  It's only from cloudflare the redirect happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: We wouldn't redirect unless you had a PageRule in place instructing us to do one. Please open a ticket if you continue to have issues. As I said, the curl I did showed it coming directly from the server.

Comment: Same problem here with prototypo.io hosted on rhcloud and DNS managed by cloudflare. Did you manage to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me with Open Shift.  All I had to do was add an alias for my domain to the gear running the app and the redirects worked properly.